# Get maximum value of a field in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model `Foo` in my models.py like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get the max `quantity` from the table. How can I get that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use Django [Aggregations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Max

Foo.objects.all().aggregate(Max('quantity'))

# or 

Foo.objects.aggregate(Max('quantity'))

# or ignore empty quantities

Foo.objects.filter(quantity__isnull=False).aggregate(Max('quantity'))

# how to get the max value

max_quantity = Foo.objects.aggregate(Max('quantity')).get('quantity__max')
```

Comment: you dont need to use **`.all()`**

Comment: Yeah, started with that and then considered to edit it, but let's keep both

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I tried adding something to this but it says `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'`  How can I add an integer to this value ?

Comment: hmm, it may be because some quantities are null, let me update the answer

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea No there are no null quantities, I think maybe it is because it returns a dictionary and we cannot use `query + 1` directly.. Can I get the result in `int` ?

Comment: `max_quantity = max_query.get('quantity__max')`

Comment: Thanks, it solved a huge problem, but out of curiosity when i tried fetching it and increasing like this it didn't work.. `Foo.objects.aggregate(Max('quantity'))['quantity'] + 1`

Comment: For that you should get `quantity__max` instead of `quantity`

Comment: With the same variable `quantity` you can assign Max() into `quantity` like this... `Foo.objects.aggregate(quantity=Max('quantity'))['quantity'] + 1`

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this for your solution...

```
from django.db.models import Max
Foo.objects.all().aggregate(Max('quantity'))['quantity__max']
```